# Removing and putting new contents in a component of React JS

Tags: reactjs

i m new to ReactJS, can u help me and tell me where am I going wrong.I want to enter details in a particular div and on the click on submission button the details should come up in the same div replacing the older contents.

I am attaching my piece of code

```
<body> <div id="container1"></div> <div id="container2"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    var userName;
    var company;
    var Example =React.createClass({
        display:function(){

        userName=this.refs.userName.value;
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = userName;

        company=this.refs.company.value;
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = company;
       },

      render:function(){
            return(
              <div>
              <form>
              Username <input type="text" ref="userName"></input><br></br>                    
              Comapany  <input type="text" ref="company"></input> <br></br>                         
              <button onClick={this.display} type="submit">Display</button>
              <Results />
              </form>
              </div>
            );
          }
        });

  var Results = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
          return (
              <div id="results">
              <p id="para"> {userName} {company} </p>
              </div>
          );
      }
  });
      ReactDOM.render(<Example />,document.getElementById('container1'));
      ReactDOM.render(<Results/>,document.getElementById('container2'));
    </script></body>
```

Comment: I think you should start from basics of ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from basics of React. Check [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/learning-react-getting-started-and-concepts) or [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html)

You could solve your problem as follows :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

      this.state = {
        username: '',
        company: '',
        showResults: false
      }
    }

    handleChange(field, e){
        let state = this.state;
        state[field] = e.target.value;
      this.setState({state});

    }

    display(){
        this.setState({showResults: !this.state.showResults})
    }

    render(){
        let showResults = this.state.showResults ? <Results {...this.state} /> : "";
        return (
        <div>
            Username <input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "username")} value={this.state.username}/><br></br>                    
            Comapany  <input type="text" name="company" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "company")} value={this.state.company}/> <br></br>                         
            <button onClick={this.display.bind(this)} type="submit">Display</button>
            {showResults}
        </div>
      )
    }
}

class Results extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
           <div id="results">
              Username : {this.props.username} <br />
              Company : {this.props.company}
          </div>
        )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[Here is fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1586/)

But I suppose that you won't understand it, thus learn first basics of React.